# Warning in file statement

Tags: python, warnings

I am getting warning :`Assignment to reserved built-in symbol: file`
on this comand:

```
file=open(fileName,'r')
```

Any Specific reason?

Comment: What part of the message don't you understand?

Comment: The reason is that you are assigning to a reserved built-in symbol, which is `file`.

Answer (score 6):

[`file`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) is a built-in global name in Python.  It's warning you not to redefine it.